# org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException

Tags: elasticsearch

I face the similar problem like http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/New-to-Elastic-Search-I-get-this-exception-org-elasticsearch-action-UnavailableShardsException-td3244381.html.

I have a master node with config:

```
cluster.name: geocoding
node.name: "node1"
node.master: true
node.data: false
index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 0
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["localhost"]
```

and a data node with config:

```
cluster.name: geocoding
node.name: "node2"
node.master: false
node.data: true
index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 0
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["localhost"]
```

Started both master & data node , running on 9200 & 9201 resp.

When i connecting for made index (using the following source), I met err(org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException).

Source code:

```
ImmutableSettings.Builder builder = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder();
    builder.put("node.client", true);
    builder.put("node.data", false);
    builder.put("node.name", "node3");
    builder.put("cluster.name", "geocoding");
    builder.put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", "false");
    builder.put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts", "localhost");
    builder.build();
    Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().settings(builder).node();
    client = node.client();
print(client.admin().cluster().prepareHealth().setWaitForGreenStatus().execute().actionGet());
```

It prints:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "geocoding",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : true,
  "number_of_nodes" : 3,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 4,
  "active_shards" : 4,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 16
}
```

Any suggestions?

Edited:
@AndreiStefan: 
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v

```
index  shard prirep state      docs store ip              node  
india  2     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
india  2     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
india  0     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
india  0     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
india  3     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
india  3     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
india  1     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
india  1     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
india  4     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
india  4     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
mytest 4     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
mytest 4     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
mytest 0     p      STARTED       0  115b <my ip> node2 
mytest 0     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
mytest 3     p      STARTED       1 2.6kb <my ip> node2 
mytest 3     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
mytest 1     p      STARTED       0  115b <my ip> node2 
mytest 1     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
mytest 2     p      STARTED       0  115b <my ip> node2 
mytest 2     r      UNASSIGNED
```

Exception detail:
org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException: [india][4] Primary shard is not active or isn't assigned is a known node. Timeout: [1m], request: index {[x][y][1], source[{"message":"a",}]}

Edited:
Full source:

```
HashMap<String, String> documentMap = new HashMap();
            String id = "1";
            String indexName = "india";
            String indexType = "address";

            ImmutableSettings.Builder builder = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder();
            builder.put("node.client", true);
            builder.put("node.data", false);
            builder.put("node.name", "node3");
            builder.put("cluster.name", "geocoding");
            builder.put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", "false");
            builder.put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts", "localhost");
            builder.build();

            Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().settings(builder).node();
            Client client = node.client();
            XContentBuilder contentBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject();

            Iterator<String> keys = documentMap.keySet().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                contentBuilder.field(key, documentMap.get(key));
            }
            contentBuilder.endObject();

            IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex(indexName, indexType, id).setSource(contentBuilder).execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: If you run `GET /_cat/shards?v` what do you get back?

Comment: @Andrei Stefan : i didnt found anything whe executing GET /_cat/shards?v

Comment: What do you mean? It should have listed the shards from all the nodes. How did you execute that command. Use `curl`/`marvel` to execute it.

Comment: @AndreiStefan: I got the above result when executing.

Comment: Have you disabled allocation? Have you physically moved folders? Have you deleted folders from `/data` directory?

Comment: No i didnt moved physically, also not deleted anything

Comment: Have you had this cluster with more than one data node in it?

Comment: If you did have more than one data node in this cluster and you created that index - `india` - and then shut down one node, took it out from the cluster, then started the remaining node ONLY, this might be the reason for the error. Basically, you don't have some primary shards around.

Comment: @AndreiStefan:Thanks for your effort. But even now freshly started master & data nodes resp. using the above config with index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 1. But still face the same err. Attached my whole java code used to made index.